# php - search for specific substring

Tags: php, regex, string

I am trying to figure out how to search in php for substring. When I tried using this:

```
while ($row = db_fetch_array($results)) {
if(strpos($row['field_rep_contact_name_value'], $get)) {
  $names['suggestions'][] = $row['field_rep_contact_name_value'];
}
}
```

I found that when the $get value was 'arm', it returned true for strings which had 'ar', I only want it to return true if it contains 'arm', the full value of the $get variable. I think this can be done with regex but not exactly sure how.

Comment: are you saying that you want to find if `$get` is contained in `$row['field_rep_contact_name_value']` or if they match exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `!== false` to your statement

```
$stringone = 'lucas vieira';
$stringtwo = 'luca';

strpos($stringone, 'lucas') !== false // returns true

strpos($stringtwo, 'lucas') !== false // returns false
```